# Cannot read property 'setHistory' of undefined What's wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What is wrong with this code? Please, help me, im beginner!

```
const App = () => {
  const [activePanel, setActivePanel] = useState("main");
  const [scheme, SetScheme] = useState("space_gray")
  const [history, setHistory] = useState(['main'])



  return (
        <Epic activePanel={activePanel}
             history={history}
             UpdateTheme={UpdateTheme} >
          <Tabbar>
            <TabbarItem
            onClick= {this.setHistory}
            selected={this.setActivePanel === 'main'}
            data-story="main"
            text="Главная"
            ><Icon28NewsfeedOutline /></TabbarItem>

            </Tabbar>
          </Epic>
  )
}
```

I'll so glad if you will help me! Thanks! I work in MVS. Trying to create mobile app

Comment: it's just `setHistory` not `this.setHistory`

Comment: In functional components there's no `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Its a functional component, so `this` will not work as expected. Just do:

```js
onClick={setHistory}
```

Same will go for `setActivePanel` but in that case I don't think you want to use the setter function. The way its written you would be reassigning the setter. I think you want to use the value:

```js
selected={activePanel === 'main'}
```

You're probably used to seeing `this` before things because it's referencing methods that belong to a class component. In a functional component, you just use variables - so no `this`.